# What are the conventions for stdout/stderr messages?

Tags: c, posix, stdout, stderr, printf

I have an app that will `fprintf` both help and error messages to `stderr`.

Should I send messages to `stdout` if I am exiting with status `EXIT_SUCCESS` (such as when I issue the `--help` option to my app)?

Likewise, should I keep sending error messages to `stderr` on `EXIT_FAILURE`?

Or should I send all help and error messages to `stdout`?

What are general conventions for this with POSIX-compliant UNIX applications?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clearly error messages should go to `stderr`, because you don't want to capture them when redirecting standard output.

When the usage is displayed because some command line option was invalidly used, then it's being shown as (part of) an error message.  So it should go to `stderr` and cause `EXIT_FAILURE`.

When the usage is being displayed because the user asked for it via `--help`, then it's being shown as the desired behaviour of invoking the command.  So it should go to `stdout` and the command should succeed with `EXIT_SUCCESS`.

This is briefly covered in the [GNU coding standards](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/_002d_002dhelp.html).

Answer (score 4):

According to the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/), *standard error* is used *for writing diagnostic output*. They seem to leave it up to the applications to define what is *diagnostic output*.

However, in my not so humble opinion, I dislike applications that write their help-text on `stderr`, because it's harder to do a simple `grep` on the text. I would say it's 50/50 which programs does this and which does not.

Comment: Yep, I agree: help text should go to `stdout`.

Comment: I dislike applications that print their help text on stdout, because if I want to grep something from the program and the arguments are wrong, I still might be fooled. If I'm grepping standard error to see if there was an error, my mechanism doesn't signal it because the help text due to the wrong call evaded it. If I want to really grep the help text for some reason, I just use <program> |& grep .

Answer (score 2):

Posix defines the standard streams [thus](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stdin.html):

> At program start-up, three streams shall be predefined and need not be opened explicitly: *standard input* (for reading conventional input), *standard output* (for writing conventional output), and *standard error* (for writing diagnostic output). When opened, the standard error stream is not fully buffered; the standard input and standard output streams are fully buffered if and only if the stream can be determined not to refer to an interactive device.

The [GNU C Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Standard-Streams.html) describes the standard streams similarly:

> Variable: *FILE* * **stdout**
> The standard output stream, which is used for normal output from the program.
>
> Variable: *FILE* * **stderr**
> The standard error stream, which is used for error messages and diagnostics issued by the program.

Thus, standard definitions have little guidance for stream usage beyond “conventional/normal output” and “diagnostic/error output.” In practice, it’s common to redirect either or both of these streams to files and pipelines, so consider the likely usage. Regular output should go to `stdout`, *especially* if users are likely to `grep` or otherwise analyze it. Help text in particular should go to `stdout` so that it can be easily searched and paged. Some systems monitor `stderr` for output and consider it a sign of problems, so generally use it only for actual errors and other significant diagnostics. And finally, only send interactive output (like progress indicators) if the stream is actually interactive (e.g., as reported by [`isatty`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isatty.html#tag_16_251)) or when explicitly enabled by a command-line option.

Comment: Oops, I meant to post this [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/331611/do-progress-reports-belong-on-stderr-or-stdout/331808#331808) instead. I will clean this up to make it a more appropriate answer for this specific question.

Comment: This should be clarified: Help text should go to stdout **when your program is run in `--help` mode**, because in that case it's what the user asked you for so it's your program's intended output. When your program is printing help text _because it was called incorrectly_, by contrast, that help text is diagnostic in nature (not the thing the user was expecting/requesting!) and belongs on stderr -- that way it doesn't get swept up in the output that's being sent to a pipeline or a file where the user will never see it.

Answer (score 1):

By using `strace` you can find that many GNU/Linux utilities (like `ls`, `date`, `gcc`, `make`   ...) output their `--help` to *stdout*. I suggest doing like they do.