# How to print something with AWK without putting it into the pipeline

Tags: awk, printing, pipeline

I have a huge csv file (277 millions of rows).
I want to verify which fields are the primary key. My idea is to do something like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {print $2,$3,$4,$5}' namefile.csv | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

If the number I get is the same of "`wc -l namefile.csv`" it means that this key is unique.

The problem is that this will take a lot of time!
Is there a way to print something on the screen (but not into the pipeline!) whenever five millions rows are elaborated?

The idea of writing a log file could be the answer....

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {print $2,$3,$4,$5; {if (NR % 5000000 == 0){print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),NR/1000000 > "log.txt"}}}' namefile.csv | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

...but doing so I can see the log file only at the end of the execution. I would like to be able to see it even during the execution.

What could I do?

Comment: The standard answer to this would be to print those messages to standard error. That's what it was invented for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the conventions for stdout/stderr messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977852/what-are-the-conventions-for-stdout-stderr-messages)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Yes, the stderr is a good answer for my question, I have never used it before.

Comment: `cut -d';' -f2-5` would produce the same output but I expect would execute much faster than `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {print $2,$3,$4,$5}'` since `cut` does less work per input line than `awk`. You dont need awk or cut or uniq, though, you could just do `sort -t';' -u -k 2,5 namefile.csv | wc -l` to get the count of those unique fields.

Comment: Depending how likely it is for their to be duplicates you could also consider doing `awk 'BEGIN{FS=SUBSEP=";"} seen[$2,$3,$4,$5]++{exit 1}' namefile.csv` in which case `$?` will contain 0 if no dups, 1 otherwise. That may be faster as `cut -d';' -f2-5 | awk 'seen[$0]++{exit 1}'` as then awk wouldn't need to do field splitting. In other words, consider changing your code to speed it up rather than just leaving it slow and printing progress markers.

Comment: Thank you for your advices! You understood very well that my question is twofold. I want to see the progress of the execution, but of course a more efficient way to obtain the same result is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You apparently only want to know if you have duplicate keys in your CSV file, where the keys are a group of fields (`$2;$3;$4;$5` in your example).

I suggest to give a try to GNU `sort` and start your pipeline with it. It is very fast. It can run in parallel up to 8 jobs if you have 8 cores.

So, you can first use `sort` to sort via your key, and pipe its output to `awk`. `awk` detects duplicates by comparing the key of the current record with the key of the previous one, aborts on the first duplicate to save time, and prints your progression. Finally you can pipe the output of `awk` to [`tee`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/tee.html) to duplicate the standard output, send one to your standard output and the other to your log file:

```
sort -t';' -k2,5 namefile.csv | awk -F ';' '
  {key = $2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5}
  NR>1 && key == prev {print "dupe: " key; exit}
  {prev = key}
  (NR % 5000000) == 0 {print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), NR / 1000000; fflush()}' |
  tee log.txt
```

Note the `fflush()` in the `awk` script to avoid output buffering.

Note: if your key is not a group of contiguous fields (e.g., `$2;$3;$4;$7`) use several `-k` options:

```
sort -t';' -k2,4 -k7,7 namefile.csv
```

Comment: Thank you for your example. It's a good idea to use first sort and then awk. Moreover I have never used tee so far and I ignored the existence of the command fflush().

Answer (score 0):

> but doing so I can see the log file only at the end of the execution.

You might use `tail -f file.txt` to observe current content of file, simple example, let `writer.sh` content be

```
for i in $(seq 1 100);
do
    echo $i >> file.txt
    sleep(1)
done
```

then open 2 terminals and run

```
bash writer.sh # in 1st terminal
tail -f file.txt # in 2nd terminal
```

you will see new numbers as they are added to `file.txt` in 2nd terminal.

If you are strictly limited to 1 terminal then write to [`/dev/stderr`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Special-FD.html) what you want to appear in your terminal, simple example which computes squares written to `squares.txt` and write message to `/dev/stderr` for numbers divisible by 10

```
seq 100 | awk '{print $1^2}$1%10==0{print("Done squares up to " $1)>"/dev/stderr"}' > squares.txt
```

Comment: It's an excellent idea to open another terminal to read the log while it's being written. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid multiple passes over `namefile.csv` by:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {print $2,$3,$4,$5}' namefile.csv |
sort |
uniq -d
```

Output will be the non-unique keys. Pipe into `wc -l` to summarise.

There are various programs that can show progress of data through a pipeline. For example, with [`pv`](https://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {print $2,$3,$4,$5}' namefile.csv |
pv -l |
sort |
uniq -d
```

> pv - Pipe Viewer - is a terminal-based tool for monitoring the progress of data through a pipeline. It can be inserted into any normal pipeline between two processes to give a visual indication of how quickly data is passing through, how long it has taken, how near to completion it is, and an estimate of how long it will be until completion.
>
> Additional support is available for multiple instances working in tandem, to given a visual indicator of relative throughput in a complex pipeline

If using coreutils version of `cat`, `gzcat`, etc, there is [`progress`](https://github.com/Xfennec/progress):

> a tiny, dirty C command that looks for coreutils basic commands (cp, mv, dd, tar, gzip/gunzip, cat, etc.) currently running on your system and displays the percentage of copied data. It can also show estimated time and throughput, and provides a "top-like" mode (monitoring)

Comment: Thank you for your advices, I only use uniq and uniq -c, but uniq -d seems very efficient. Unfortunately pv doesn't work, maybe because I have Bash Unix.